# How to make sure a 3 character filename contains one of 2 characters?

Tags: command-line

So I have to search a directory for files that are of 3 character length. That is easy, the problem is that at least 1 of the 3 characters needs to be either a "B" or a "y". I know that [By] would make sure the character is either a B or a y, however simply doing [By][By][By] would not suffice since it is not a requirement for all 3 characters to be either B or y; only 1 of them has to be. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command(s):

```
cd /path/to/directory
ls | while read file; do if [ ${#file} -eq 3 ]; then echo $file; fi; done | grep '[By]'
```

or:

```
for file in ???; do echo $file; done | grep '[By]'
```

or, a variant without any loop:

```
ls | grep -ow '\w\{3\}' | grep '[By]'
```

`ls` will list all files from the current directory, then we select only the filenames that have exactly 3 characters in length and finally, using `grep`, we select only filenames that contain `B` or `y`.

Comment: Hmmm is there no way to do it without looping? Thank you.

Comment: The `ls` isn't doing anything in the otherwise-superior second command...

Comment: try the simpler: `ls -1 ./??? | grep '[By]'`  (the option to ls is "minus one", not "minus L". `-1` ensures that ls lists files one by one, 1 per line)  (and the `./` is there so that even if the filename you find starts with a `-` it can still be used with an xargs, or other command). You can also add `-li` to also display the full details + the inode, but then the grep should take into account the fact that "B" or "y" may be somewhere in the details (ex: May).

Comment: @JohnStacen Yes, there is. See my new edits in the answer.

Comment: There's probably not filenames with whitespace in this case, but treating filenames as lines is a bad practice in general. Though the main problem here is that the pattern provided to grep should be quoted, if the current directory contains a file named `B` and one named `y`, the shell will replace `[By]` with `B y`, so you end up running `grep B y` which will look for lines matching `B` in the file named `y`; ignoring stdin completely.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu, I'm not high, no, and I appoligize if you found my comment to be "nasty". Try setting up a test directory to run your command line in, and check that it gives the expected output. Now run `touch B y` and run the line again. Does it still give the expected result?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu lies. `touch abc aBc def xyz; ls | grep -ow '\w\{3\}' | grep [By]` outputs `aBc` and `xyz`. Now still in the same directory, and without removing any files: `touch B y; ls | grep -ow '\w\{3\}' | grep [By]` outputs nothing, since the file named `y` is empty.

Comment: @geirha Why should I lie? Look here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BJJQT.png

Comment: @RaduRădeanu, ah you're not using a posix shell. Try it with bash, the default login shell in ubuntu.

Comment: -1 because 1) [Never parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), 2) what @geira said, 3) What is the point of piping `ls` to `for` anyway? It does exactly the same thing as the `for` loop alone. 4) You `grep -ow ` does not do what you think it does, it will simply print out the first 3 characters of _every_ file that contains three successive `[A-za-z_]` characters followed by a non word one, so it will also match on `foo123` or 123foo` etc, irrespective of its length.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf '%s\n' ??? | grep '[By]'
```

The `printf '%s\n'` prints each argument passed to it, one-per-line; the `???` is a glob that expands to every three-character filename in the working directory. This is piped to the `grep`, which prints only those filenames containing the pattern you specified.

By the way, I found myself using `printf '%s\n'` so much that I put the following in my `~/.bashrc` for ease-of-typing:

```
alias necho='printf "%s\n"'  ##  newline-echo
```

Most of the time this will be fine: it will break on filenames containing newlines, but those are pretty rare in fact (I've only ever seen them when I've made them specifically to test scripts of mine). It's probably possible to whip up a simple pure bash solution using [extglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob), but you could also use `find` to work around this issue:

```
find . -name '???' -a -name '*[By]*'
```

This will act recursively by default; if you don't want that, use `-maxdepth 1`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '???' -a -name '*[By]*'
```

Comment: See my comment to Radu Rădeanu's answer.

Comment: @geirha I know that it's best-practice to make things safe for newlines... but honestly, I've only ever seen such files when I've created them to test scripts of mine. However, I'll whip up a `find`-based solution to make things absolutely safe. If you're referring to quoting the `[By]` -- good point, that was a silly mistake.

Comment: `+1` for the `find` solution! you'll be able to `-exec` stuff safely with that one, or to further filter (as said with, e.g., `-maxdepth` or `type f`, etc.). And it might be quicker than Bash globbing if there's a huge number of files.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a pattern match in a for-loop.

```
for file in ./???; do
    [[ -e $file && $file = *[By]* ]] || continue
    printf 'Do stuff with <%s>\n' "$file"
done
```

Or you can enable extended globs by running `shopt -s extglob`. Then you can use something like `@([By]??|?[By]?|??[By])`

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in ./@([By]??|?[By]?|??[By]); do
    [[ -e $file ]] || continue
    printf 'Do stuff with <%s>\n' "$file"
done
```

Either will be more efficient than involving `grep`.

If you're scripting for POSIX sh, you could do something like this:

```
for file in ./???; do
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue
    case $file in 
        *[By]*) : ;;
        *) continue;;
    esac
    printf 'Do something with <%s>\n' "$file"    
done
```

Lastly, you could use three globs, though that will iterate the files in a different order and you risk iterating the same file multiple times.

```
for file in ./[By]?? ./?[By]? ./??[By]; do
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue
    printf 'Do something with <%s>\n' "$file"    
done
```

Comment: If a file was found using `for file in ...`, why should you have doubts about its existence? :D

Comment: @RaduRădeanu if there are no files matching the glob, the glob will be passed on as the word to iterate, unless nullglob is enabled.

Comment: +1 for a pure bash solution, but if you're going to use extglob then you may as well use nullglob too. With nullglob, you could even avoid using a loop, if all you want is a list of the names -- `printf '%s\n' ./@([By]??|?[By]?|??[By])`